# Qt TCP server running readyRead() in seperate thread

Tags: qt, sockets, tcp, qt5, qthread

I am very new to both Qt and socket programming.

I am trying to write a simple TCP server/chat app but the `readyRead()` or "receiving" part is in it's own thread. I got this "working" using UDP but for some reason the TCP sockets don't work the same way.

I am very open to other suggestions as I may be tackling this in the wrong way. I eventually will be having this app listening to a continuous input from an embedded system, reading and writing commands and also receiving a "heartbeat" from the system.

I have been following YouTube tutorials by Voidrealms and have been implementing threads "The right way". But I am now not able to run `qThread::exec()` as it is protected.

So basically I would like a `sender` and `receiver` in **different threads**, so that the `sender` does not block the `receiver` and visa versa.

I will post just the TCP server code and the working UDP code for reference.

tcpserver.h

```
#ifndef TCPSERVER_H
#define TCPSERVER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QThread>

class TCPServer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TCPServer(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void SendData();
    void DoSetup(QThread &cThread);
   // void readyRead();
       bool conn;

signals:

public slots:
   void newConnection();
   void readyRead();
   void DoWork();


private:
       QTcpServer *server;
       QTcpSocket *socket;
};

#endif // TCPSERVER_H
```

tcpserver.cpp

```
#include "tcpserver.h"
#include <QThread>

TCPServer::TCPServer(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    this->conn =0;
    server = new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(server,SIGNAL(newConnection()),this,SLOT(newConnection()));

    //telnet 169.254.55.237 1234
    if(!server->listen(QHostAddress("169.254.55.237"),1234)){
        qDebug() << "Server not started";
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << "server started";

    }
}

void TCPServer::DoSetup(QThread &cThread){
    connect(&cThread,SIGNAL(started()),this,SLOT(DoWork()));
}

void TCPServer::DoWork(){
    qDebug() << "Running Thread";
    connect(this->socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
}


void TCPServer::SendData(){
    while(1){
        QByteArray Data;

        Data.append("Server: ");

        QTextStream s(stdin);
        QString value = s.readLine();
        Data.append(value);

        this->socket->write(Data);
        //this->socket->write("hello client\r\n");
        this->socket->flush();
        this->socket->waitForBytesWritten(3000);
    }
}

void TCPServer::newConnection(){

    this->socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
    //connect(this->socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readyRead()));
    this->conn =1;
    this->SendData();

   //this->socket->close();
}

void TCPServer::readyRead(){
    // while(1){
    if(this->conn){
        qDebug()<< "Reading...";
        qDebug()<< this->socket->readAll();
}
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "tcpserver.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QThread cThread;
    TCPServer mServer;

    mServer.DoSetup(cThread);
    mServer.moveToThread(&cThread);

    cThread.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

WORKING UART.
myudp.h

```
// myudp.h

#ifndef MYUDP_H
#define MYUDP_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

class MyUDP : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyUDP(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void HelloUDP();
    void DoSetup(QThread &cThread);
    //void readyRead();

signals:

public slots:
    void readyRead();
    void DoWork();

private:
    QUdpSocket *socket;

};

#endif // MYUDP_H
```

myudp.cpp

```
// myudp.cpp

#include "myudp.h"

MyUDP::MyUDP(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    // create a QUDP socket
    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);

    socket->bind(QHostAddress(" 169.254.55.237"), 1234);

    //connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
}

void MyUDP::DoSetup(QThread &cThread){
    connect(&cThread,SIGNAL(started()),this,SLOT(DoWork()));
}

void MyUDP::DoWork(){
qDebug() << "Running Thread";
connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
}

void MyUDP::HelloUDP()
{
    while(1){
    QByteArray Data;
    Data.append("Server: ");

    QTextStream s(stdin);
    QString value = s.readLine();
    Data.append(value);

    socket->writeDatagram(Data, QHostAddress("169.254.55.237"), 4321);
    //socket->writeDatagram(Data, QHostAddress("127.0.0.1"), 1234);
}
}

void MyUDP::readyRead()
{
   // if(socket->hasPendingDatagrams()){
    // when data comes in
    QByteArray buffer;
    buffer.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());

    QHostAddress sender;
    quint16 senderPort;

    socket->readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(),&sender, &senderPort);

    qDebug() << "Message from: " << sender.toString();
    qDebug() << "Message port: " << senderPort;
    qDebug() << "Message: " << buffer;

   // }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include "myudp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "Server";

    QThread cThread;

    MyUDP client;

    client.DoSetup(cThread);
    client.moveToThread(&cThread);

    cThread.start();

    client.HelloUDP();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Is it possible to further condense your code into a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? (Emphasis on the minimal - 2+ screens of code are a bit much)

Comment: Something that is stated by the docs which might be the reason your code doesn't work: [*Note: The returned QTcpSocket object cannot be used from another thread. If you want to use an incoming connection from another thread, you need to override incomingConnection().*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#nextPendingConnection). Not sure if *from another thread* means different than the main thread, or different from the `QTcpServer `'s thread.

Comment: @CharonX , Thanks for the feedback. Do you suggest I remove the working UDP example?

Comment: @thuga , Thanks. This seems like it may be a lead. following the link I found " If you want to handle an incoming connection as a new QTcpSocket object in another thread you have to pass the socketDescriptor to the other thread and create the QTcpSocket object there and use its setSocketDescriptor() method."  So I will try work out how to pass the Socket descriptor and create an object like they describe.

Answer (score 0):

After a comment form @thuga, and some research, It seems to me that it is not possible (or not advisable) to have read and write functionality in separate threads. A `QTcpSocket` is not thread safe. It seems the best solution is to create worker functions in separate threads that emit a signal for the main thread (or thread with `QTCPSocket`) to act on. For Example a worker function to read input from a user can be put in a new thread and when there is new data, a signal can be emitted that will indicate it can be sent by the `QTCPSocket`.

Threading for `QTCPSocket`s seem to be more for handling multiple connections all within their own threads.

links below:

- https://forum.qt.io/topic/18692/sending-and-recieving-qtcpsocket-in-different-threads/2
- [how to use QTcpSocket in multithread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592122/how-to-use-qtcpsocket-in-multithread)
- https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/56840-QTcpSocket-write-to-socket-from-several-threads